# React JS создать счетчик без useState (чтобы не обнулялся)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hook

В моем проекте есть кнопка для копирования элемента (table). При копировании каждая новая копия создается с именем и порядковым номером. При закрытии страницы стейт обнуляется, если я хочу создать еще несколько копий элемента потом, счетчик снова именует их с нуля, это создает ошибку в работе приложения.
Как можно написать функцию для счетчика, чтобы он начинал отсчет с порядкового номера последней копии. Вот мой код:

```
const [copyTableCounter, setCopyTableCounter] = useState(0);
const onCopyTable = (element) => {
        const copiedTable = {
            id: table.id,
            name: `${element.name}_COPY (${copyTableCounter})`,
            position: {
                x: element.position.x + 5,
                y: element.position.y + 5,
            },
            columns: table.columns,
        };

        onCopyTableHandler(copiedTable, areaName);
    };
```

Comment: Вы же наверняка ваши элементы где то сохраняете, в localStorage к примеру? Можно же при старте приложения посчитать количество элементов и установить это число как начальное состояние

Comment: Еще вариант, модифицировать функцию так, что бы она передавала текущее количество элементов, тогда от переменной состояния можно избавиться

Comment: @SwaD нет, в lS оно не сохраняется. Сохранение только в имени копированной таблицы. Можно ли как-то оттуда его подтянуть?

Comment: Тогда не очень понятно... Вот приложение стартануло, есть некий начальный набор элементов. Ну понасоздавали мы еще несколько. Закрыли приложение. Все созданное удалилось. Открываем заново приложение - почему оно выводит ошибку при том же начальном наборе данных?

Comment: @SwaD в json добавляется при сохранении запись новой таблицы {"id": "1", "name": "Table_Name_COPY (0)"} и так далее. Это единственный вариант, откуда я могу получить порядковый номер копии. Но как реализовать эту функцию - ни малейшего понятия((

Comment: Ну т.е. вновь созданное где то сохраняется все таки? Покажите как выглядит ваш JSON, что бы можно было дать адекватный ответ + как вы его получаете

Comment: {
                    "id": 11,
                    "originalTableId": 3129,
                    "name": "MY_TABLE_COPY (1)",
                    "position": { "x": 14.0, "y": 445.0 },
                    "columns": []; }
Просто в силу обстоятельств я не могу полный json предоставить.  Это элемент последний, то есть скопированная таблица, записанная в json.
В json отправляет новую таблицу onCopyTableHandler();

Comment: И это у вас в массиве лежит, верно(Массив объектов свойств таблицы)?

Comment: @SwaD да, объект diagram, внутри массив areas, внутри него массив tables, а этот объект уже в нем

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Допустим, есть объект(если я правильно понял из комментариев):

```
const diagram = {
  areas: [{
    tables: [
      { "id": 11, "originalTableId": 3129, "name": "MY_TABLE_COPY (1)", "position": { "x": 14.0, "y": 445.0 }, "columns": [] },
      { "id": 12, "originalTableId": 3128, "name": "MY_TABLE_COPY (1)", "position": { "x": 14.0, "y": 445.0 }, "columns": [] },
      { "id": 13, "originalTableId": 3127, "name": "MY_TABLE_COPY (1)", "position": { "x": 14.0, "y": 445.0 }, "columns": [] }
    ]
  }]
}
```

Тогда можно начальное состояние устанавливать исходя из текущих данных

```
// Начальное состояние - максимальный id
const [copyTableCounter, setCopyTableCounter] = useState(diagram.areas[0].tables.map(el => el.id).sort((a,b) => b - a)[0]);

// Начальное состояние - количество элементов в tables
const [copyTableCounter, setCopyTableCounter] = useState(diagram.areas[0].tables.length);

// Или напрямую использовать в фукнции без сохранения в переменной состояния
// т.к. это не требует дополнительных вычислений
name: `${element.name}_COPY (${diagram.areas[0].tables.length})`,
```

Я бы предложил в areas создать новый ключ, назовем его tableCounter(к примеру) и смотрел бы на него и при изменении данных по таблицам менял бы это значение

```
const diagram = {
  areas: [{
    tables: [],
    tableCounter: 0 // вот тут хранить нужное значение для текущей areas
  }]
}
```

Мне кажется этот вариант проще, наглядее и управляем + он попадет в ваш текущий механизм сохранения данных.

Comment: Спасибо!!! Да, так это работает корректно.

Comment: Но есть проблема: в areas может быть несколько таблиц. Если я копирую любую из них, то порядковый номер первой скопированной будет уже не 0...

Comment: @MIA Тогда попробуйте ключ `tableCounter` переделать в какой нибудь справочник вида `tableCounter: {t1: 0, t2: 0}` или сделать его массивам по индексам таблиц `tableCounter: [0, 0]`. Не видя всей структуры ваших данных очень сложно дать точный ответ. Тут как бы вариант, как это можно организовать.